# Проблема переполения

Tags: c#

Мне нужно получить числа 6 в ^ (x*x) (максимально возможное значение x - 251) и x ^ x, чтобы потом найти остаток от деления этих чисел на 251.
Какое может быть решение?

Comment: [Алгоритмы быстрого возведения в степень по модулю](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E)

Comment: А что порекомендуете?)

Comment: А вот ничего :-) какой понравился тот и реализуйте :-)

Comment: А нормального примера по Монтгомерине встречали? Так чтобы на пальцах.

Comment: А что-то непонятно в описании в википедии? там вроде даже алгоритмы приведены

Comment: Да они написаны по инопланетянски, как и большинство статей википедии.

Comment: Ну например воспользуйтесь тем, что остатки последовательных степеней числа периодичны по любому модулю. Найдите период, дальше очевидно. Или примените малую теорему Ферма. В конце-концов, если вы занимаетесь криптографией, спросите у математика, который пишет вам алгоритмы.

Comment: я вопрос перенес сюда http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514873/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8