# Алгоритм Монтгомери

Tags: c#, c++, c, алгоритм

Об алгоритме удалось найти только статью на [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8), но там написано всё непонятно для кого и непонятно кем. Поскольку я не очень силён в теории вычетов и дискретном логарифмировании, прошу помочь разобраться с реализацией, можно приводить примеры на языках c#, c, c++.

Сначала разбираемся с умножением.

Выдержки из статьи:

> По данным целым числам a, b < n, r, НОД(r,n)=1 алгоритм Монтгомери
> вычисляет
>
> MonPro(a,b) = a * b * r^-1 mod n

Алгоритм реализует умножение чисел по модулю (a*b) mod n.

> Положим r=2^k.
>
> Определим n-остаток (n-residue) числа a < n как a' = a * r mod n

Как я понял, нам нужно подобрать такое k, чтобы r > n.

> MonPro вычисляет c' = a' * b' * r^-1 mod n

Как посчитать b'?

> MonPro(a,b) = a * b * r^-1 mod n

Или это и есть алгоритм?

Вопрос буду дополнять по мере разбора.

Comment: По-моему, вопрос смысла не имеет. Это как написать `a*b = a+a+a...+a b раз` и спрашивать, что это за числа `a` и `b` и откуда их брать? Или - откуда брать `a` и `b` при решении уравнения `ax=b`? Применяется это все для вычисления произведения `ab` *по модулю* `n`.

Comment: По-моему, я ясно ответил - **умножение `a` на `b` по модулю `n`**. Не непосредственно, а как именно - описано там же, в Википедии.

Comment: Это я уже понял, кто-то написал уже в ответе, но потом удалил. У меня другой вопрос созрел.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот фотка из моего учебника (переписывать, честно, лень). Все понятно вроде (почти код на Паскале). Надеюсю, Вам поможет. Обоснование, думаю, не надо?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что за учебник, если не секрет?

Comment: @zed наш вузовский курс лекций.